# Securing user credentials over unidirectional UDP-connection

Tags: c#, security, udp

I'm building a mobile viewer app which should show real time data from sensor systems. The project has strict security restrictions so my webserver which will serve the apps with data must be located in a DMZ outside the secure net. The data I'm exporting is washed and considered safe to use over the internet, but as always I'd like to encrypt user credentials somehow.

I can only communicate from the secure net out to the DMZ, so any protocols that requires handshaking would'nt work.

The company framework I have to work in the secure net is built with .NET technologies. In the DMZ I'm free to use whatever i find suitable.

The one idea i have is that i could hardcode a shared secret into both applications and test any incoming messages against that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how end-to-end mail encryption works, that is have a look at PGP or S/MIME.  With end-to-end mail encryption you have to address the same problems because you have to secure your data without having any kind of handshake.

They way this is done is that the sender knows the public key of the recipient and encrypts the data with this key. Only the owner of the matching private key (the recipient) can decrypt the data. This is easier to protect than having a shared secret, because with a shared secret all of the communication peers must have access to the secret, while with public-private-key cryptography only the recipients needs to have access to the secret (the private key).

Apart from that, security.stackexchange.com might be a better forum to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look on that!

And yeah security.stackexchange.com is probably more on-topic.